# Lynx command line browser and the 'hosts' file

Tags: web-server, hosts-file

I am building a small web app for my company and currently I have this weird issue:

I have 2 instances of the web app running, one accessible through the internet and another one for internal purposes and testing only. The internal version has a public IP address though.

When I try to access the public version of the app with the Lynx command line browser I get what I am supposed to get. So far so good. Now, when I make changes to the hosts file, so that when I try to access the app I would get the 'internal' version, what comes back is again the public version.

On top of that, there seems to be a problem only with my app. Any other website is correctly blocked or redirected when I make changes to the hosts file.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried this:

When running `getent hosts` I get the correct list from the `/etc/hosts` file. When I run `getent hosts www.example.com` though I get the 'outside' address, although the correction is clearly in place.

Comment: @HBruijn Thanx for the edit. Speed typing got the best of me.

Comment: And `getent hosts <fully-qualified-hostname>` does indeed return the correct ip-address that you set up in `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: @HBruijn No it does not actually. Although it is clearly in the file, and appears when 'getent hosts'... when 'getent hosts <...>' I get the 'outside' address.

Comment: Hmmm then check nsswitch.conf which governs the order/priority of the different name resolution options are used. DNS maybe be placed before files.

Comment: @HBruijn Where might that be?

Comment: The most obvious location for configuration files: `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. BTW I edited your question to reflect SF policy to either use your own domain name or example.[com|org] rather than "made up" domains that may exist and don't belong to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20209/discussion-between-dsljanus-and-hbruijn).

Comment: @HBruijn No... It says: 'hosts: files dns myhostname'

Comment: maybe internal lynx cache of webcontent?